# Navigation stays highlighted after clicking on it

Tags: html, css

Hi i just wanted some help trying to animate my navigation bar. I want the nav link to still be highlight after I have clicked on the page. So for example if I pressed a "home" button while on the home page the home button would be highlighted to just to show that your definitely on this page. Would use :target or ::active?

```
<div id="header-content">
            <div class="hire"><h3>For Hire</h3></div>
            <h1><a href="index.html">Black Cab Tours</a></h1>

                    <nav class="cl-effect-8">
                    <ul>
                <li><a onclick="tours.html" href="#tab1">Tours</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a css class like

```
.active {
 background: #c2c2c2;
}
```

when u click on a HOME page link add this class to that **li** tag through java script here is the code

```
$('li').click(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

or you can use gt(), lt() selector to remove active class from else **li** tags

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Javascript (e.g. jQuery) to assist you, in native CSS `:active` will only style the current interaction state as it occurs, `:target` may be unreliable if you rely on routing, and the final option `:focus` will fail when clicking elsewhere.

By using jQuery you can more tightly maintain control over the application/removal of a selected state, e.g:

```
$('#header-content li').on('click', function(){
     $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

This isolates the relevant elements, adds the class `selected` when you click one, and removes it from its siblings.